# Unable to start phonegap application in eclipse

Tags: android, cordova, droidgap

I have import several open source phonegap application in eclipse and they can be compiled and installed on the devices. The issue is, when I start these applications, Android will always throw a dialog saying "Unfortunately, (App Name) has stopped". After observing the log files, I found that for all the apps, the logcat print almost same message during crash. I copy these message here:

```
08-09 14:48:07.906: W/dalvikvm(1984): Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/ztepc/rss/RssReaderActivity; (43)
08-09 14:48:07.906: W/dalvikvm(1984): Link of class 'Lorg/ztepc/rss/RssReaderActivity;' failed
08-09 14:48:07.906: D/AndroidRuntime(1984): Shutting down VM
08-09 14:48:07.906: W/dalvikvm(1984): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x42077438)
08-09 14:48:07.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1984): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-09 14:48:07.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1984): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{org.ztepc.rss/org.ztepc.rss.RssReaderActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ztepc.rss.RssReaderActivity
08-09 14:48:07.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2012)
08-09 14:48:07.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2113)
08-09 14:48:07.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:139)
08-09 14:48:07.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1224)
...more
```

It seems that the the superclass of my main activity which is DroidGap cannot be resolved. I check the properties of my project, the codorva-*.*.*.jar is in the java build path, the it has been checked in the "order and export" tab.

Any suggestion is welcomed.
Thanks!